# Mongoose virtuals are not added to the result

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm building a quiz editor where rounds contain questions and questions can be in multiple rounds. Therefor I have the following Schemes:

```
var roundSchema = Schema({
  name: String
});

var questionSchema = Schema({
  question: String,
  parentRounds: [{
    roundId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Round'},
    isOwner: Boolean
  }]
});
```

What I want is to query a round, but also list all questions related to that round.

Therefor I created the following virtual on `roundSchema`:

```
roundSchema.virtual('questions', {
  ref : 'Question',
  localField : '_id',
  foreignField : 'parentRounds.roundId'
});
```

Further instantiating the Round and Question model and querying a Round results in an object without questions:

```
var Round = mongoose.model('Round', roundSchema, 'rounds');
var Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema, 'questions');

Round.findById('5ba117e887f66908ae87aa56').populate('questions').exec((err, rounds) => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(rounds);
  process.exit();
});
```

Result:

```
Mongoose: rounds.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5ba117e887f66908ae87aa56") }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: questions.find({ 'parentRounds.roundId': { '$in': [ ObjectId("5ba117e887f66908ae87aa56") ] } }, { projection: {} })
{ _id: 5ba117e887f66908ae87aa56, __v: 0, name: 'Test Roundname' }
```

As you can see, I have debugging turned on, which shows me the mongo queries. It seems like the second one is the one used to fill up the virtual field.

Executing the same query using Mongohub DOES result in a question:
[image]

So why doesn't Mongoose show that `questions` array I'm expecting?

I've also tried the same example with just one parentRound and no sub-objects, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself...

Apparently, I have to use

```
console.log(rounds.toJSON({virtuals: true}));
```

instead of

```
console.log(rounds);
```

Why would Mongoose do such a devil thing? :(